# Do we have our own database?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

There are so many actors all around the world, and we can also get the information on wikipeia. But can we create our own database for the information (accurate). And can we make another search box option for the information about any movie or an actor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site, we are not a database of movie information, e.g. IMDB or a Wiki of Movie and Actor information as Wikipedia is in many cases. In both cases the information contained by these sites should be verifiably accurate - e.g. wikipedia encourages references for all information.

The role of Stack Exchange is to post questions and have several possible answers, and people vote the best answer to the top.

No Stack Exchange site has such a feature, and we are not going to be the first to do so as we are only a beta site.

Comment: I think he is saying to have a Wikipedia/IMDb like pages for Actors.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I wondered that as well but thought it too far fetched.  Will edit